# Linux, write output to file, including the command

Tags: linux, bash

How can I write into a file the output of a command but also include the command at the beginning of a file?

eg:

```
grep -nrs 'blah' . >/home/ca/out.txt
```

so that the file shows

```
grep -nrs 'blah' . >/home/ca/out.txt
./something.cpp:1329:    if(blah)
```

to leave a blank line between?

```
grep -nrs 'blah' . >/home/ca/out.txt

./something.cpp:1329:    if(blah)
....
```

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you want [script(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) ?

Comment: all are right answers, thank you very much, I will just choose the one that suits me best

Comment: I'm glad @BasileStarynkevitch mentioned `script` - I love that command, but haven't used it for years; and if you don't remember the name, hard to do an `apropos` to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store command line and result both in a file using `bash -vc` like this:

```
bash -vc "grep -nrs 'blah' ." >& /home/ca/out.txt
```

- `-v` is for verbose mode in bash that outputs full command before executing it.
- `-c` is for running a command from command line
- `>&` is for redirecting both stdout and stderr

---

Another approach is store command line in an array:

```
arr=(grep -nrs 'blah' .)
{ printf "%q " "${arr[@]}"; echo; echo; "${arr[@]}"; } >& /home/ca/out.txt
```

Comment: Inserting a newline after command isn't easy with this approach. One needs to store whole command line an array and then insert newlines (see edit)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `logsave` ([usage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logsave)) to log the output together with a timestamp and the command, e.g.:

```
logsave -a output.txt ls
```

Saves the output of the `ls` command into output.txt:

```
Log of ls 
Thu Jan 29 16:49:25 2015

[output of command]

Thu Jan 29 16:49:25 2015
----------------
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use it in a bash-script you can first write and echo line and then add the output to the file:

```
echo "grep -nrs 'blah' ." > /home/ca/out.txt
grep -nrs 'blah' . >> /home/ca/out.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `script` command to save both command and output in same file, as follows

```
script -a mycommands.txt
```

Once the section to be recorded is complete, type `exit` in terminal to exit the program.